# Jquery plug-in for annotation and mark-up tools

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi I need a plug for a toolbar,it should contain menu's like zoom in,zoom out,full image,rotate left rotate right,magnifier etc.I attached an image to show how the tool bar should look like.
Is there any Jquery plug-in Like that?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: @NeelBhatt,Thanks for the link,I just want to know if there is a plug in so that it will save my time,I need the approch only,kindly note this i am not expecting that someone has to do my entire work.Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here are some links which might can solve your problem

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/12/20-best-web-annotation-and-mark-up-tools.html

http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download/jquery-image-markup-annotation-tools-4375165.html